# Eclipse Export Wizard is not displaying the Export for multiple platform option

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

In eclipse when i do export and select 'Eclipse product' option. I found that it is not displaying the option 'Export for multiple platform option'. I don't know what i did so that this option vanishes. Previously it displayed me this option. what can be the possible reason for this ?

Comment: Have to installed the Eclipse RCP Delta pack?

Comment: But i didn't uninstall this pack, Previously it showed me this option but for some reason. It is not displaying it now.

Comment: The delta pack does not appear in any install site. You must download it yourself and install in your target platform. See http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseProductDeployment/article.html#deployment_deltapack